# panels collapsible reload page instead hide panel | angularjs | bootstrap | ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm losing my mind with this code:

```
<div class=" col-md-3 col-lg-2 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <div class="panel-group" id="mainMenuCollapsible">
        <div ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#mainMenuCollapsible" href="#collapse_{{ $index }}">
                            {{ item }}
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse_{{ $index }}" class="panel-collapse collapse" >
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        BLA BL
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There no chance to get this working. When I click the title of any panels page reloads showing the panel selected but with no visual effects. My code is exactly the same as bootstrap [example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-examples).

I have all jss in the right place (jquery 2.0.3, bootstrap.min 3.0.2, angular 1.2).

I also tried removing ng-repeat and doing with a single panel with no luck. What am I missing? **Many thanks**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my self. It's angular that intercept the route #collapse_X. Using data-target instead of href:

```
data-target="#collapse_{{ $index }}"
```

solved perfectly!

Hope this helps someone.